# Why doesn't combn() using paste0 as the FUN give me the expected result (r)

Tags: r, combn

I'm trying to create a list of combinations of strings using `combn()` with `paste0` as the function, but all I get back is the matrix of combinations. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
combn(LETTERS[1:5],3, FUN=paste0)
```

Gives me:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "C"  
[2,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "C"  "C"  "D"  "C"  "C"  "D"  "D"  
[3,] "C"  "D"  "E"  "D"  "E"  "E"  "D"  "E"  "E"  "E"
```

When what I expected to get was something like:

```
[1] "ABC" "ABD" "ABE" "ACD" "ACE" "ADE" ...
```

What did I miss?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `combn`; `paste0(c("a", "b", "c"))` vs `paste0(c("a", "b", "c"), collapse = "")`

Comment: THANKS! This has been frustrating me since yesterday. Didn't think to check is paste0 was the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use this command and see if it works ? It worked for me.

```
combn(LETTERS[1:5],3, FUN=paste0, collapse = "")
```